# How to add attribute and value to xml tag in scala(spark) by using databrick

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

I need to add "xml:lang" as attribute and "shirt" as value in display-name tag in spark scala using data bricks. Please help.
for example - 

`<display-name xml:lang="x-default">Shirt</display-name>`

Comment: please provide more details of your issue and requirement

Comment: @Nikk Updated the question with example..

Comment: check it for more details https://github.com/scala/scala-xml/wiki/Getting-started

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the databricks spark-xml library as shown below:

1. Import the spark-xml library into your workspace
   OR
2. Attach the library to your cluster

[image]

3. Use the following code in your notebook to read the xml file, where "note" is the root of my xml file.

> xmldata = spark.read.format('xml').option("rootTag","note").load('dbfs:/mnt/mydatafolder/xmls/note.xml')
>   display(xmldata)

Example :

[image]

For more details, refer "[XML Data Sources for Apache Spark](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml)".

Hope this helps.